# Generic Inventory Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Edit: I've been thinking of how to give a tl;dr here. How about this: Inspector is looking for a BaseObject. How can I get the inspector to allow me to assign a DerivedObject, derived from BaseObject.

I'm trying to make a generic inventory system. I've tried out Brackey's inventory system, but wanted to expand upon it to include things beyond just an "Item". I'd like to have a "Key" or "Weapon" classes that inherit Item as a base, whereas Brackey's Inventory has a number of Boolean fields that determine if it is able to be equipped or if it's a weapon. I can do this, my problem is how do create these items at editor time, when my script is expecting  base Type: Item.

Starting from scratch I have an Item (Fields: string ItemName) and I have Key : Item ( New Fields: string AuthorityLevel)

I've got a Pickup script that I apply as a component to GameObjects. In that script I can give it a property of Item, and when the GameObject is interacted with I can call the Pickup.GetItem() method. This then takes the Item property and adds it to my Inventory object.

How would I get that Item property to hold a reference to a Key object, which inherits from Item? The inspector for the PickUp script will only show the Item Property's "ItemName", rather than the Key Item's AuthorityLevel field.

I'm a little lost. I've found it easy to implement this at runtime, since the scripts that create items, know what specific item to create and can assign it to the newly created GameObject's PickUp script. But at Editor time, it's difficult to tell the inspector that I want the Pickup script to hold a reference to Key or any other object that inherits from Item.

Comment: Have you been able to find an answer to your question yet? :) I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: Hey Roy. I haven't found a solution just yet. The project I was working on was just me trying to play around with some ideas, so I put it on the backburner to work on some simple things.

However, I did recently see something that I thought might solve this problem. I put it in the back of my mind, figuring I'd try it sometime down the road. Maybe you'll find it just as interesting:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/1xu0bg/release_full_inspector_inspector_serialization/

Comment: Thanks for the link, quite a coincidence as I just spotted it before you commented here! It's looking really nice and the author seems to reply on questions as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is almost 7 years old, but for anyone searching this up:

I don't think there is any actual issue here, a `List<Item>` can store references to any class that inherits from Item.

Therefore having an array or a list of a class type allows referencing any object of a derived class.

example:

```
public class Item
{
    //some attributes
}
```

and

```
public class Weapon : Item, IEquippable, IAttack //etc
{
    //weapon stuff
}
```

can just be stored in

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Derived class D from base class B

```
class D : public B
{
//staff or nothing
}
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: Hey Java. I know how to derive a class from another. In my example above: (Edit, because apparently you can't press enter here.)

class key : item { }

The problem is when I have a component that expects an object of type Item. I want to pass it a Key object, which is an Item, but I can't do so at Editor time. It's easily done at runtime.

Comment: can you post some code, or the code that you are having troubles with ?